# Socket emits multiple events for each room client connects to

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, sockets

My react-native component is receiving socket events for each previous room it connects to.

I have a simple component that when it mounts it tries to join a socket room and when somebody else joins the room it tries to fetch the most recent room data.

When I load the lobby the first time, I can join the room fine and the server emits an event to say "updateRoom" and each connected client receives the event and calls the update method.

If I navigate back a screen and then come back into the lobby to join a new room I receive 2 events that a new member has joined. 1 appears to be for the old room and 1 for the new room. If I repeat this step over and over I keep getting additional events received for each time I leave and start a new room.

My component looks like so:

```
class LobbyScreen extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      route: {
        params: {
          roomId
        }
      },
      socket,
      user
    } = this.props

    socket.on('updateRoom', () => {
      getRoom({ roomId })
    })

    socket.emit('joinRoom', {
      roomId, 
      userId: user._id
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        ...
      </View>
    )
  }  
}
```

And I have a simple socket server for handling connections and receiving and emitting the event of joining the room:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {

  socket.on("joinRoom", ({ roomId, userId }) => {

    socket.join(roomId, () => {
      io.to(roomId).emit("updateRoom", { userId }) // tells everyone in the room that user with userId joined
    })

  })

})
```

Comment: I don't know react but i can guess that every time your component is mounted socket is subscribed to `updateRoom` event.  you should use singleton pattern for socket, subscribing to rooms should not be in component mounting logic. if it has to be in component mounting logic, then you should check if socket is already subscribed to that room `io.adapter.allRooms(function (err, rooms) {...});`

Comment: @Moazzam The roomId comes from the route param though so it is a different value each time I visit that screen.

Comment: that's the point, your component is subscribing to new room every time, but doesn't t call `room.leave()`  when it is destroyed. basically it is subscribed to multiple rooms.

Comment: You're correct that the client is not leaving the room. But the server should only be emitting the event to one room where the user joined `io.to(roomId).emit`.

Comment: well, in that case  what if you use `io.sockets.in(roomId).emit('updateRoom', {userId});` on server

Comment: That didn't seem to resolve the issue and seems to work the same as the previous code, You did make me realise that after restarting the server I am still getting multiple events logged on the client. This made me realise that the client must have multiple listeners so adding `socket.off('updateRoom');` when component unmounts seems to have solved this. I'm guessing the server emits an event to a client ID and if the client  has multiple listeners it actions the event for each listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillUnmount` to unsubscribe from the socket event whenever the user leaves the view. This is a react lifecycle method that calls just before the component is navigated away from.

Depending on the socket framework there will be a `close` method you can call to close the connection, or in your case you can probably find a method that unsubscribes from the room.

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
  socket.close()
}
```

Obvs this is oversimplified but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your server code not react!
if a user is supposed to be present in just one room at a time, you should change the code to:

```
socket.on("joinRoom", ({ roomId, userId }) => {
    socket.leave(PREVIOUS_ROOM); // leave previous room before joining a new one
    socket.join(roomId, () => {
    io.to(roomId).emit("updateRoom", { userId })
})
```